# Python Flask .txt file Encoding

Tags: python, encoding, flask

I am using Jinja2 template with Flask application.
When reading contents from uploaded .txt file, I get the result as

```
'\xff\xfeA\x00e\x00r\x00 \x00L\x00i\x00n\x00g\x00u\x00s\x00 \x00h\x00a ...'
```

Although I can see the correct file contents in the debugging console.

My code is like

```
@main_app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    file = request.files['file']
    if file:
        filedata = file.read()

    return render_template('page.html',
        components = [{'filecontents': filedata}]
    )
```

I tried solutions from other questions, such as suggesting to use .encode() and .decode(), but they didn't work.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copied from the [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/unicode/#encoding-and-decoding-yourself):

```
def read_file(filename, charset='utf-8'):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        return f.read().decode(charset)
```

Use your file encoding as `charset`, e.g.:

```
test_string = '\xff\xfeA\x00e\x00r\x00\x00L\x00i\x00n\x00g\x00u\x00s\x00 \x00h\x00a ...'
print test_string.decode('latin')
>>> ÿþA
```

I am just guessing that your file is `latin` encoded.

Answer (score -3):

Try putting

```
import sys
reload(sys).setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
```

at the start of your code.

Comment: do not fiddle with `setdefaultencoding ` http://ziade.org/2008/01/08/syssetdefaultencoding-is-evil/